# Variable containing Log is receiving null

Tags: php, laravel

I am wanting to create a log that informs the registration of a new user, the problem is in the line, i'm wanting to create a log that informs the registration of a new user, the problem is in the line `$log_message = Log::channel('logRegisterUser')->info("{$name_user} registered using the IP {$ip_user} in {$data}.");` which when placed in a `dd()` is revealed as `null`. With this creating error at line `'description_log' => $log_message,`.

- `logging.php`

```
        'logRegisterUser' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/logRegisterUser.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],
```

- `RegisteredUserController.php`

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->logModel = new LoggingModel();
    }
    
    public function create()
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);

        event(new Registered($user));

        $date = Carbon::now()->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
        $name_user = $user->name;
        $ip_user = request()->ip();
        $log_message = Log::channel('logRegisterUser')->info("{$name_user} registered using the IP {$ip_user} in {$data}.");

        $this->logModel->create([
            'description_log' => $log_message,
            'relation' => '',
        ]);

        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
```

Comment: `Log::info()` doesn't return a value. What are you expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting ```"{$name_user} registered using the IP {$ip_user} in {$data}."```

Comment: I'd suggest assigning that line to a variable, then pass that variable into both `Log::info()` and into your logModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log->info() does not return a value. Instead write message in your variable first and then pass it to your Logger :

```
$log_message = "{$name_user} registered using the IP {$ip_user} in {$data}."; 
Log::channel('logRegisterUser')->info($log_message);
```